# Java socketChannel to detect disorderly closed connection

Tags: java, sockets, nio, socketchannel

I know that a SocketChannel is "notified" about an orderly closed connection by receiving "-1" after calling read().

But how can it notify me about an disorderly closed connection? (as part of a whole NIO based server, working with selector and non-blocking socketChannels)

Comment: Why would some -1 this question? What's wrong about it? the minimum you can is to explain.

Comment: You've received "-1" because you had an orderly closed connection :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `write()` will throw `IOException: connection reset`. Eventually. Due to TCP buffering it won't happen on the first write after the failure.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, but that is the only way? what if I only expect to read as a server?

Comment: Also, What will happen if after it is disorderly closed I will call socket.close()? will it block because it might wait for the OS tcp connection closure?

Comment: You may or may not get the reset if you only read. `close()` never waits, unless you're in blocking mode and have done silly things to SO_LINGER.